# Ploting a mathematical function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to plot the data which is shown below and compere it to a function which gives me the theoretical plot. I am able to plot the data with its uncertainty, but i am struguling to plot the mathematical function function which gives me the theoretical plot.

```
     amplitude  uncertainty position 
     5.2       0.429343685  0 
     12.2      1.836833144  1 
     21.4      0.672431409  2 
     30.2      0.927812481  3 
     38.2      1.163321108  4 
     44.2      1.340998136  5 
     48.4      1.506088975  6 
     51        1.543016526  7 
     51.2      1.587229032  8 
     49.8      1.507327436  9 
     46.2      1.400355669  10 
     40.6      1.254401849  11 
     32.5      0.995301462  12 
     24.2      0.753044487  13 
     14        0.58         14 
     7         0.29         15
```

here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_excel("Verdier_6.xlsx")

verdier = data.values

frekvens = verdier [:,3]
effektresonans = verdier [:,0]
usikkerhet = verdier [:,1]

x = np.arange(0,15,0.1)
p= 28.2
r=0.8156
v= 343.8
f= 1117

y=p*np.sqrt(1+r**2+2*r*np.cos(((2*np.pi)/(v/f))*x))

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.plot(frekvens, effektresonans)
plt.errorbar(frekvens, effektresonans, usikkerhet, fmt = "o")


plt.title("")
plt.xlabel("Posisjon, X [cm]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude, U [mV] ")

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And here is here is a image of the plot with only experimental data shown above:
[image]

and here is an image of how my experimental and theoretical plot look:
[image]

and here is an image of how the experimental and theoretical plot should look:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that `plt.plot(x,y)` does not plot the mathematical function `y=p*np.sqrt(1+r**2+2*r*np.cos(((2*np.pi)/(v/f))*x))`?

Comment: it do but i get a worng plot it dose not come out the way its supposed to, when i plot the same function i geogera the plot l get what i expected but not in python. if you look above you can see what i get, i just uploded a image of what i get.

Comment: Looks like the x values used to calculate the theoretical plot are scaled incorrectly (or in other words, the function used to calculate the theoretical plot uses the given x values incorrectly). Have you tried replacing `(2*np.pi)` by `1`?

Comment: yes, iam sure the problem lies with x. but i have noe idea how to fix it.

Comment: (2*np.pi) is part of the function i cant change it

Comment: You can at least *try* it to see if *hypothetically* this would give you the result you want.

Comment: i did it dose not work